# Rectangle Extraction from XY / Line Coordinate Set

Tags: c#, shapes, extract

So I'm looking for approaches to try to extract rectangular shape(s) from a bounded (enclosed) shape defined by XY coordinates. At the outset I know the following:

- XY of every point
- What each XY point is connected to

Example of a basic square:

- XY set: [[0, 0], [0, 10], [10, 0], [10, 10]]
- Known: [0, 0] connects to [0, 10], [10, 0], etc...

Some of the problems are:

1. Bounding XY set is not necessarily XY aligned, so it could be
   something like (diamond when looking straight on): [0, 0], [3.5,
   3.5], [0, 7], [-3.5, -3.5]
2. Bounding XY set does not necessarily define a quadrilateral or even
   a 4 sided shape. It could be more complex like an L shape, U shape.
3. 3) I'm also interested in multiple rectangle combinations in more
   complex shapes. Such as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtRMv.png

I'm fine with setting some realistic boundaries, for instance just saying something is too complex:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tim5S.png

My initial thought process was to maybe find the outer corners (e.g. top left max Y min X) and try to find sides, so something like:

[0, 10] is top left

[0, 10] connects to [0, 0], [10, 10]

Find right side for [0, 10] -> [0, 0] by finding point connection with closest X that falls along Y coverage [Y from 0 -> 10 is covered].

So we would end up finding [10, 10] -> [10, 0].

Repeat for closest Y that falls along X coverage [X from 0 -> 10 is covered] and find [0, 0] -> [10, 0]

Then expand this to find partial overlaps (like in an L shape there may be 2 Y segments that overlap on the right side of the corner line).

Not articulating this as well as I would like, but I think the general idea of what I'd like to accomplish is clear. I was wondering if anyone was aware of any existing approaches or logic to approaching such issues.

Comment: How close to 90° do you want adjacent sides to be and still be considered ok for rectangle extraction?

Comment: In an ideal world it would be only 90 degree angles, but I'm willing to allow some flexibility +- a couple degrees and assume something at 88 or 92 is close enough.

Comment: I would recommend going to triangle tesselation first and then seeing if you can merge two adjacent triangles to form a rectangle.